# For contact, can eye, sights, and eye-consciousness arise but NOT meet?

Tags: pali-canon, sutras

[From MN 148](https://suttacentral.net/mn148?view=normal)

Bhante Sujato

> Eye consciousness arises dependent on the eye and sights. The meeting of the three is contact.

Bhikkhu Bodhi

> Dependent on the eye and forms, eye-consciousness arises; the meeting of the three is contact.

Pali

> Cakkhuñca paṭicca rūpe ca uppajjati cakkhuviññāṇaṁ, tiṇṇaṁ saṅgati phasso;

Can you have the internal base, the external base, and consciousness but they **do not** meet? If so, what is an example?

Answer (score 2):

The confusion arise in you because of mis interpretation of

> tiṇṇaṁ saṅgati phasso;

It should not mean 'contact of three'. Because arising of consciousness itself is connecting the two. it is  connector.

> Cakkhuñca paṭicca rūpe ca uppajjati cakkhuviññāṇaṁ

**Actual meaning of sangati is  going together. sam+gati.**

so as long as the eye is there and object is there and consciousness is there, there exist phassa. It can happen that the arised consciousness may drop before the phassa. due to lake of interest. or the object itself drop due to  fast movement. or the eye moves away. in all such case there shall not be phasso which can generate vedana.

Answer (score 1):

generally speaking, as i understand it, the meeting of the internal-external-consciousness creates contact named eye-consciousness, ear-consciousness, etc.  i don't particularly understand the idea of 'gives rise to' or arises, as if the contact was moving up like smoke or vapor, but whatever that's another topic.

but your question:
Can you have the internal base, the external base, and consciousness but they do not meet? If so, what is an example?

it's not a clear question to me, but as I understand it, contact is only for 1 of 6 senses at any given time.  so yes, 5 of 6 senses are contactless ie do not meet.

then it seems 6 of 6 also not meeting in higher jhana according to [AN 9.37](https://suttacentral.net/an9.37/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin):

> The eye itself is actually present, and so are those sights. Yet one
> will not experience that sense-field. The ear itself is actually
> present, and so are those sounds. Yet one will not experience that
> sense-field. The nose itself is actually present, and so are those
> smells. Yet one will not experience that sense-field. The tongue
> itself is actually present, and so are those tastes. Yet one will not
> experience that sense-field. The body itself is actually present, and
> so are those touches. Yet one will not experience that sense-field.”

Comment: That sutta doesn't explicitly mention contact. It could be that eye, forms, and eye-consciousness are not meeting to make contact OR there is eye and forms but no eye-consciousness.

Comment: from my understanding, there is only one consciousness.  eye-, ear-, etc. is contact, ie 6 types of contact.

Comment: the sutta seems to imply a consciousness not within the body, but i'm not sure

Comment: There are six classes of consciousness https://suttacentral.net/sn12.2/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin

Comment: yes, you are right. but i don't believe it. what good is tongue-consciousness without a tongue? i believe in one consciousness and six types of contact

Comment: if i say, machine-white is representing time and you say, no, it's representing white, are you saying it's two distinct consciousnesses at play?  i am willing to listen but I think it is not that way..

Answer (score 0):

No. Eye-consciousness can only arise when the eye & the form meet. [MN 38](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.038.than.html) says:

> Apart from a requisite condition, there is no coming-into-play of
> consciousness.
>
> Consciousness, monks, is classified simply by the requisite condition in dependence on which it arises. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the eye & forms is classified simply as eye-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the ear & sounds is classified simply as ear-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the nose & aromas is classified simply as nose-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the tongue & flavors is classified simply as tongue-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the body & tactile sensations is classified simply as body-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the intellect & ideas is classified simply as intellect-consciousness.
>
> Just as fire is classified simply by whatever requisite condition in dependence on which it burns — a fire that burns in dependence on wood is classified simply as a wood-fire, a fire that burns in dependence on wood-chips is classified simply as a wood-chip-fire; a fire that burns in dependence on grass is classified simply as a grass-fire; a fire that burns in dependence on cow-dung is classified simply as a cow-dung-fire; a fire that burns in dependence on chaff is classified simply as a chaff-fire; a fire that burns in dependence on rubbish is classified simply as a rubbish-fire — in the same way, consciousness is classified simply by the requisite condition in dependence on which it arises.